# Need clarity on Webgl Shaders configuration and parameters to achieve the desired results

Tags: javascript, typescript, webgl, shader, 2d-games

I want to apply wave effect on water spritesheet from top to bottom direction in way that it looks animated. I got some piece of code from internet but it's creating some effects but in random manner. I want to control it as per my requirement.[image: Below is the image on which I want to apply wave effects] Below is the code:

```
function CustomFilter(customSprite, ambientColor, resolution) {
        PIXI.Filter.call(
            this,
            null,
            (
                `
               varying vec2 vTextureCoord;
            uniform sampler2D uSampler;
            uniform float u_ctime;
            const int iterations = 1;
            const float view = 3.;
            void main()
            {
                    vec2 fragCoord = vTextureCoord;
                    vec2 iResolution = vec2(1.0,1.0);
                    float iGlobalTime = u_ctime;
                vec2 uv = fragCoord.xy;
                uv *= view;
                for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
                float ang = atan(uv.y+cos(uv.y*2.+iGlobalTime)*.5,
                uv.y+sin(uv.y*2.+iGlobalTime)*.5)-length(uv)*.1;
                float sn = sin(ang);

                 mat2 m = mat2(sn,sn,sn,sn);
                 uv = uv*.15-abs(uv*.5*m);
                }

                float d = length(mod(uv,1.)-.5)-.4;

                d *= 20.;
                vec4 FragColor = vec4( sin(uv.x*d), sin(d+.5346), -sin(d+uv.x*1.63), 1. )*.5;
                vec2 u_Scale = vec2(0.0,0.07)*sin(u_ctime);
                vec3 displace = FragColor.rba;
                displace.xy *= displace.z * u_Scale*(0.5-fragCoord.x);
                gl_FragColor = texture2D( uSampler, vTextureCoord + displace.xy );
            }

            `
            )

        );
```

Answer (score 0):

The base base functions for wave effect are `sin` or `cos`, and if you look closely, you will see that your super complex shader is full of that. Paradoxically, this is way more complex to acheive randomness than a regular wave.

For example, to draw a wave along X (horizontal) axis, with variation on Y (vertical) axis, you would use this function:

```
let frequency = 2.0;
let amplitude = 1.0;
let y_base = 0.0;
for(x = 0.0; x < 1.0; x += 0.01) {
  point.x = x;
  point.y = y_base + (sin(x * frequency) * amplitude);
}
```

Pretty simple, no ? You simply have to apply this concept to your shader, for example, with texture sampling. So, if you want, for example, create a wave effect along X axis, you can use something like that:

```
 float f = 5.0;
 float a = 0.05;
 vec4 waved = texture2D(sampler, vec2(coord.x, coord.y+(sin(coord.x*f)*a)));
```

If you want add some animation, you simply have to add a kind of time variable (in your shader, this is currently `u_ctime`), and the pseudo-code will look like this:

```
let time = clock();
let pitch = 0.5;
let frequency = 2.0;
let amplitude = 1.0;
let y_base = 0.0;

for(x = 0.0; x < 1.0; x += 0.01) {
  point.x = x;
  point.y = y_base + (sin((time * pitch) + x * frequency) * amplitude);
}
```

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Unit_circle_definition